# Installing cloudfoundry gives Authentication error with Openstack; How can I debug an Opensource project? Namely, bosh on Openstack?

Tags: validation, cloud-foundry, openstack, rackspace

I am trying to create a Bosh Microinstance on my Rackspace Server and am getting the following error:

```
E, [2013-10-29T15:17:25.113723 #30341] [0xc9c00c] ERROR -- : Unable to connect to the OpenStack Compute API. Check task debug log for details.
I, [2013-10-29T16:38:36.928221 #1754] [0x335004]  INFO -- : No existing deployments found (will save to /root/bosh-deployments.yml)
I, [2013-10-29T16:39:14.636310 #1768] [0xfa9010]  INFO -- : Loading existing deployment data from: /root/bosh-workspace/deployments/bosh-deployments.yml
I, [2013-10-29T16:39:20.766583 #1768] [0xfa9010]  INFO -- : bosh-registry is ready on port 25889
I, [2013-10-29T16:39:26.731953 #1768] [0xfa9010]  INFO -- : Loading yaml from /tmp/d20131029-1768-ewe5t0/sc-20131029-1768-ansv2l/stemcell.MF
E, [2013-10-29T16:39:28.626135 #1768] [0xfa9010] ERROR -- : Expected([200, 204]) <=> Actual(401 Unauthorized)
  response => #<Excon::Response:0x0000000382cdc0 @data={:body=>"{\"unauthorized\":{\"code\":401,\"message\":\"Unable to authenticate user with credentials provided.\"}}", :headers=>{"Server"=>"nginx/0.8.55", "Date"=>"Tue, 29 Oct 2013 16:39:27 GMT", "Content-Type"=>"application/json", "Transfer-Encoding"=>"chunked", "Connection"=>"keep-alive", "vary"=>"Accept, Accept-Encoding, X-Auth-Token", "VIA"=>"1.0 Repose (Repose/2.3.5)"}, :status=>401, :remote_ip=>"72.3.138.129"}, @body="{\"unauthorized\":{\"code\":401,\"message\":\"Unable to authenticate user with credentials provided.\"}}", @headers={"Server"=>"nginx/0.8.55", "Date"=>"Tue, 29 Oct 2013 16:39:27 GMT", "Content-Type"=>"application/json", "Transfer-Encoding"=>"chunked", "Connection"=>"keep-alive", "vary"=>"Accept, Accept-Encoding, X-Auth-Token", "VIA"=>"1.0 Repose (Repose/2.3.5)"}, @status=401, @remote_ip="72.3.138.129"> (Excon::Errors::Unauthorized)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/excon-0.25.3/lib/excon/middlewares/expects.rb:10:in `response_call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/excon-0.25.3/lib/excon/middlewares/response_parser.rb:8:in `response_call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/excon-0.25.3/lib/excon/connection.rb:349:in `response'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/excon-0.25.3/lib/excon/connection.rb:247:in `request'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/fog-1.14.0/lib/fog/core/connection.rb:57:in `request'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/fog-1.14.0/lib/fog/core/deprecated/connection.rb:20:in `request'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/fog-1.14.0/lib/fog/openstack.rb:195:in `retrieve_tokens_v2'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/fog-1.14.0/lib/fog/openstack.rb:88:in `authenticate_v2'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/fog-1.14.0/lib/fog/openstack/compute.rb:392:in `authenticate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/fog-1.14.0/lib/fog/openstack/compute.rb:316:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/fog-1.14.0/lib/fog/core/service.rb:68:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/fog-1.14.0/lib/fog/core/service.rb:68:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/fog-1.14.0/lib/fog/compute.rb:44:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/bosh_openstack_cpi-1.5.0.pre.1181/lib/cloud/openstack/cloud.rb:55:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/bosh_cpi-1.5.0.pre.1181/lib/cloud/provider.rb:11:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/bosh_cpi-1.5.0.pre.1181/lib/cloud/provider.rb:11:in `create'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/bosh_cli_plugin_micro-1.5.0.pre.1181/lib/bosh/deployer/configuration.rb:65:in `cloud'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/bosh_cli_plugin_micro-1.5.0.pre.1181/lib/bosh/deployer/instance_manager.rb:54:in `cloud'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/bosh_cli_plugin_micro-1.5.0.pre.1181/lib/bosh/deployer/instance_manager.rb:229:in `block (2 levels) in create_stemcell'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/bosh_cli_plugin_micro-1.5.0.pre.1181/lib/bosh/deployer/instance_manager.rb:79:in `step'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/bosh_cli_plugin_micro-1.5.0.pre.1181/lib/bosh/deployer/instance_manager.rb:228:in `block in create_stemcell'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tmpdir.rb:83:in `mktmpdir'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/bosh_cli_plugin_micro-1.5.0.pre.1181/lib/bosh/deployer/instance_manager.rb:214:in `create_stemcell'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/bosh_cli_plugin_micro-1.5.0.pre.1181/lib/bosh/deployer/instance_manager.rb:118:in `create'
"microbosh-openstack/bosh_micro_deploy.log" 215L, 28192C
```

I have a .yml file set up which I can't really post for security reasons, but I've verified with my IAAS support that i have the correct credentials.

Has anyone seen an error like this on Openstack? Also I am getting a stack trace and half tempted to try debugging. Problem is I'm not well versed on debugging these large open projects. Does anyone know a good resource explaining how to begin debugging them?

Comment: in this situation you could verify the credentials work with python-keystone client.  do something like :

    export USERNAME=user;
    export PASSWORD=password;
    export TENANT_NAME=tenant;
    export OS_AUTH_URL=http://ip.address:5000/v2.0/;

    keystone --debug catalog;

And look for debug output see if that auth creds are working.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks so much for the comment. It's given me useful information. However, I actually am getting this response:
RESP: {'status': '200', 'content-length': '4698', 'via': '1.0 Repose (Repose/2.3.5)', 'vary': 'Accept, Accept-Encoding, X-Auth-Token', 'server': 'nginx/0.8.55', 'connection': 'keep-alive', '-content-encoding': 'gzip', 'front-end-https': 'on', 'date': 'Tue, 29 Oct 2013 21:01:11 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/json'}

But micro bosh deployment is returning a 401 still.

Comment: ouch.  not too familiar with bosh, so not sure how to increase verbosity on it's own debugging.  have you considered wiresharking or stracing to see what the http / conn traffic is?

Answer (score 2):

The error that you're seeing is caused by OpenStack rejecting the credentials that you're providing. One possible pitfall: are you using your Rackspace account password for "PASSWORD" instead of an API key? You can find your API key by [logging in to your account](https://mycloud.rackspace.com/), clicking on your username in the upper-right, and choosing "account settings" from the drop-down. (I'm assuming you're using Rackspace because of the question tags.)

You mentioned that you've verified them with your provider -- perhaps they aren't being passed in correctly? According to the [documentation](http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/docs/running/deploying-cf/openstack/deploying_microbosh.html), you should put them in a `micro_bosh.yml` file with the following form:

```
# ...
cloud:
  plugin: openstack
  properties:
    openstack:
      auth_url: http://<identity_server>:5000/v2.0
      username: <username>
      api_key: <password>
      tenant: <tenant>
      region: <region> # Optional
      default_security_groups: ["ssh", "bosh"]
      default_key_name: <microbosh_keypair>
      private_key: <path_to_microbosh_keypar_private_key>
# ...
```

Remember that YAML is whitespace-sensitive.

As for debugging open-source projects, the best guidance I can give is to not be afraid of the source and to have some patience. The source code for bosh is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/bosh), so you can easily [browse](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/bosh/blob/master/bosh_openstack_cpi/lib/cloud/openstack/cloud.rb#L55) [around](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/bosh/blob/master/bosh_cpi/lib/cloud/provider.rb#L11) [the](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/bosh/blob/master/bosh_cli_plugin_micro/lib/bosh/deployer/configuration.rb#L65) source code up your stack trace to try to figure out what's going on. Work backwards from the actual exception or error message that you're seeing; try to determine what was put into an unexpected state, and trace callers to figure out how it could have ended up that way. Reading other people's source code is an incredibly useful skill, and it gets easier with practice, so have at it!

Comment: Hi. I actually did use the API for the password. I also do have the micro_bosh.yml in that exact format. I will work my way up the stack trace and see what I can figure out.